# Counting times on Google Sheets (not working properly) - Phone agent log in time v call times

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp

this is potentially really simple but I have been looking at it for ages, which may be the problem.

I am looking at log in times on a phone system v the times when calls are incoming. The spreadsheet breaks down the phone hours by minute and then checks the times someone logged in and displays if they were logged in at any given minute.

Then the data from incoming calls is pasted in which is converted into timestamps and compared.

The problem is a bit odd because it correctly counts from 9:30 to around 15:00 but then does not count entries after that time.

Here is a [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I2T7m7wtdMLLZ84X3ZQGtbdVy-cg7DPU-sXwrepa0e4/edit#gid=0) copy I have made.

Any help would be appreciated. As I said it's probably really simple but often when you have looked at something too long you miss obvious things.

Comment: Can you describe your problem more in details? Which rows/ columns in your sheet give you a problem? What is the desired and what the real output?

Comment: Yes sorry not really clear. So N9:RZ9 should count if there are incoming calls. The call list is H12:H. The issue arises that the COUNTIF works but does not seem to recognise calls after 15:00 as there are calls in the list (H2:H) but no results in row 9.

Therefore it misses a number of calls coming which means you cannot then compare agents on the phone against incoming calls as its not a complete set. 

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem is due to rounding errors

For example, both cell `H72` and `MK11` have the display value `15:05:00`.

However, if you visualize the real value of the cells, e.g. by `Paste values only` into a cell formatted as a number you will see:

- The exact value of cell `H72` is `0.628472222222222`
- The exact value of cell `MK11` is `0.628472222222221`

This rounding error was not obvious for the first rows / columns but it kept propagating through the data until the point of becoming big enough to change 15th decimal position.

The reason is that Google Sheets stores numbers as 64 bit signed floating points which limits the precision to the 15th decimal position and thus rounding errors will not become obvious as long as they are smaller than this.

### Solution

Given that you use the formula

`=ROUNDUP(F12*1440/1,0)*1/1440`

on column H for the call list, you should do the same for the incoming rows in row 9, so

`=ROUNDUP(1440*(N11+time(0,1,0)))/1440`

and so on.

Comment: This is so helpful thank you. I imagined it was something to do with the timestamps being different but didn't look to the 15th decimal point.